# md-select options orderBy "code" Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in Angular Material. I have a little problem with md-select.

html code

```
<md-input-container>
        <label layout="row" layout-align="start start">Text</label>
        <md-select name="selectText"  ng-model="textArray" required>
            <md-option value="text.code" ng-repeat="text in textArray | orderBy: 'text.code'" required>{{ text.name }}</md-option>
        </md-select>
          <div ng-messages="formText.selectText.$error" ng-show="formText.selectText.$dirty || formText.selectText.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">Select is Required </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
```

Angular code

```
var textArray = [{name:"A", code:"5"},
{name:"B", code:"4"},
{name:"C", code:"3"},
{name:"D", code:"2"},
{name:"E", code:"1"}];

$scope.textArray = textArray;
```

I try to reorder options from md-select, using code, but the options are order by ('asc'), like (A, B ,C, D, E). Please can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'text.code'` by `text.code`. Use below code :

```
<HTML>
   <md-option value="text.code" ng-repeat="text in textArray | orderBy: text.code" required>{{ text.name }}</md-option>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
  <md-option value="text.code" ng-repeat="text in textArray | orderBy: 'code'" required></md-option>
```

for more reference : http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_orderby.asp

Comment: Here in ng-repeat we are getting iterated object ..so in orderBy no need to use 'text.code' ...